# Adding logging to my Perl Install script

Tags: perl, logging

I am working on writing a Perl script that will install software changes for our application. Mostly this involves running sql files in sqlplus. While I do log each sql file that gets run and grep each log file for errors, I would like to get a single log file of everything. That way if something weird happens during the install I will have a single file with everything that happened while the patch was being installed. If I was writing this in bash I would do the following:

```
exec >my_log_file
exec 2>&1
... some code runs
exec 1>&-
exec 2>&-
```

The exec command will redirect anything that goes to stdout and stderr to my log file. At the end of the script I turn that off so that I can grep the log for errors. I can also redirect stdout back to /dev/tty and cat the log if I want.

Is there a pure Perl way to get the same effect? I'm guessing that if I run the above code with the system command in Perl I am creating a new process and thus would not get all of the output from the script. I also thought about creating a bash wrapper script for the logging, but that would require the customer to run the wrapper script. It would be easier if I can do this in Perl.

Thanks.

Comment: [Log::Log4perl](https://metacpan.org/pod/Log::Log4perl)

Comment: I have looked at Log::Log4perl and it might work. The downside to that would be that our customers would have to install another Perl library. Ideally there should be something that will work and already be a part of Perl without a separate install. But I will take a look at Log::Log4perl.

Comment: There are ways to package dependencies along with your script so your users don't have to install anything. See [`pp`](https://metacpan.org/pod/pp), for example.

Comment: PP looks really interesting. I will have to check that out as well. Thanks!

Comment: Or you could create a full-fledged distribution from your script and distribute it as a tarball. If your customers can install [cpanm](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-cpanminus/bin/cpanm), installing your tarball together with all its dependencies requires only one command. To create distributions, I like to use [Dist::Zilla](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dist::Zilla), but that may be too heavy for your taste. There are lighter alternatives nowadays, e.g., [Minilla](https://metacpan.org/pod/Minilla), but I haven't used any of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is loosely adapted from an example in "[perldoc -f open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html)".

```
# Take copies of the original STDOUT and STDERR.
open(my $oldout, ">&", \*STDOUT) or die "Can't dup STDOUT: $!";
open(my $olderr  ">&", \*STDERR) or die "Can't dup STDERR: $!";

# Open STDOUT to a log file
open(STDOUT, '>', 'my_file.log') or die "Can't redirect STDOUT: $!";
# Copy STDERR to STDOUT
open(STDERR, ">&STDOUT")     or die "Can't dup STDOUT: $!";

# Unbuffer STDOUT and STDERR
select STDERR; $| = 1;
select STDOUT; $| = 1;

# Do stuff that prints to STDOUT and STDERR
...

# Restore original STDOUT and STDERR
open(STDOUT, ">&", $oldout) or die "Can't dup \$oldout: $!";
open(STDERR, ">&", $olderr) or die "Can't dup OLDERR: $!";
```

Comment: Very slight edit. the second open statement needs another comma. 'my $olderr,  ">&"'. Thanks!